# How to extract only alphabetical characters using regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I am currently trying to extract only the alphabetical portion of the string and exclude the characters in parentheses or the ones that are alphanumeric. Currently when I use my current code it will extract all alphabetical characters including the alphanumeric ones.

```
df['desc'] = df['description'].str.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+')
```

AERONAUTICAL MOBILE (OR)  AUS52 AUS57  AUS58  AUS101

How do I only get AERONAUTICAL MOBILE from this string using regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the all alpha portion the description would always start at the beginning of the string, we can use `str.extract` as follows:

```py
df["desc"] = df["description"].str.extract(r'^([a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*)', flags=re.I)
```